# Data is not loading when I come back to activity

Tags: android, firebase, android-layout, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

```
public class AllUsersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private RecyclerView mUserRecycler;

private DatabaseReference mAllUsersDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mUserRef;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;
private ArrayList<Users> users_list = new ArrayList<>();
private Users users;
private AllUsersAdapter mAllUsersAdapter;
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
String TAG = " ALL USERS ";


@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_users);

    Log.i("ON CREATE METHOD", "ALL USERS");

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.users_app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("All Users");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    mUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

    mAllUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    mAllUsersDatabase.keepSynced(true);


    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);


    mAllUsersAdapter = new AllUsersAdapter(users_list);
    mUserRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.allusers_recycler_view);
    mUserRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mUserRecycler.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    mUserRecycler.setAdapter(mAllUsersAdapter);


}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i("ON START METHOD", "ALL USERS");


}


@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    Log.i("ON RESUME METHOD", "ALL USERS");
    Get_USER();
    mUserRecycler.setAdapter(mAllUsersAdapter);

}

public void Get_USER() {

    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                String thumb_image = ds.child("thumb_image").getValue(String.class);
                //Log.i("TAG", name);
                // Log.i("TAG", thumb_image);
                users = new Users(name, thumbimage);
                users_list.add(users);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    };
    mAllUsersDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
}
```

}

I am able to get the result from firebase but when I open the activity for the first time, I am getting the data as expected on the screen but when I press the "up navigation button or back button" and come back to the activity then nothing is loaded on screen while I can see the data in logs. Also when I press the home button and again comeback then data is loaded.
My code is in OnResume method but still not working as expected. I am retrieving the list of all users registered on Firebase

Comment: There must be a better way than `users_list` but I do not know Firebase well enough

Comment: Yes there is FirebaseRecyclerAdapter but they are working only for API 21 and not with oreo and nougat

Comment: This is the issue I am facing with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50582795/firebaserecycleradapter-working-for-api-21-but-not-working-with-oreo-or-nougat

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Nothing I do seems to fix it. It simply don't load when I open activity again. Tried with the exact same code that works on MainActivity.

Comment: @JohnT  Instead of overriding onResume (), try to load your data inside onStart().

Comment: @Ayush That's what I finally did and it's working now. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

`addListenerForSingleValueEvent` is used to read data once, use `addValueEventListener(ValueEventListener)` if you want to read the data if the data is changed

```
 // remove **Get_USER** method from onPostResume and add **Get_USER** method at the end of **onCreate**
// and also remove this **mUserRecycler.setAdapter(mAllUsersAdapter)** in onPostResume method 
        public void Get_USER() {

            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                        String thumb_image = ds.child("thumb_image").getValue(String.class);
                        //Log.i("TAG", name);
                        // Log.i("TAG", thumb_image);
                        users = new Users(name, thumbimage);
                        users_list.add(users);
                        mAllUsersAdapter.notifyItemInserted(users_list.size() - 1);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            };

           mAllUsersDatabase.addValueEventListener(eventListener);
        }
```

Comment: added addValueEventListener(ValueEventListener), but now there is 3 times the data in the list and also it is not loading on coming back to activity

Comment: Tried your code but this time I am not  getting anything on the screen, only in logs